# Knockout JS if else to display different html based on value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to learn knockout and have come up against a problem.

I am trying to use the ko if clause but can't seem to work it out myself

My script so far looks like

```
  <script>
    var SimpleListModel = function (items) {
        this.questionType = ko.observable("");
        this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
        this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
        this.addItem = function () {
            if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
                var qt = $("#question-type").data("kendoDropDownList");
                this.questionType(qt.value());
                console.log(qt.value());
                this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); // Adds the item. Writing to the "items" observableArray causes any associated UI to update.
                this.itemToAdd(""); // Clears the text box, because it's bound to the "itemToAdd" observable
            }
        }.bind(this);  // Ensure that "this" is always this view model
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel([]));
    });
</script>
```

My html looks like

```
     <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Question</button>
                        <div id="questions" data-bind="foreach: items">
                            <div class="question-item">
                                <label data-bind="text: $data" class="q-label"></label>
                                <textarea placeholder="Answer" class="q-answer"></textarea>
                                 <!-- ko if: questionType()==="ABC" -->
                                           Display ABC
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if: questionType()==="DEF" -->
                                           Display DEF
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
```

What do I need to do, to get the ko if: questionType to work correctly?

I have updated the setting of the questionType as suggested however I am getting an error `Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: questionType is not defined;
Bindings value: if:questionType()==="Comment"`

Comment: `this.questionType = qt.value();` is not a valid way to set observable values. You need to pass the new value as a parameter: `this.questionType(qt.value());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `questionType` is an observable you need to call it as a function with no arguments to retrieve its value.

So, your `if` statements would need to look like:

```
<!-- ko if: $parent.questionType() === "ABC" -->
    Display ABC
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Also you want to set like this `this.questionType(qt.value());`.

Comment: Thanks guys, @RP Niemeyer I tried your suggestion however I get an error Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: questionType is not defined;
Bindings value: if: questionType()==="ABC"

Comment: It looks like your `questionType` is not on each item, but is at the root level.  Your `if` block is inside a loop over `items`.  So, you would need to specify it like `$parent.questionType()` or `$root.questionType()`

Comment: thanks......nearly there, that does the trick for the apply the correct if statement however if I try adding another item to the vm it updates the $parent.questionType value to the newly selected value. How do I make the values independent?

Comment: You probably would want your items to be objects.  Maybe that contain a type and a value.  Then you would not bind against `$parent`, but instead against the type on each item.